# Finding counterexamples to prove: $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $(0,\infty)$ does not imply $1/f_n \to 1/f$ uniformly on $(0,\infty)$

Tags: examples-counterexamples, uniform-convergence, advice

If $f_n \to f$ uniformly, where $(f_n)$ and $f$ are positive functions on $(0,\infty)$, then is it true that $1/f_n \to 1/f$ uniformly on $(0,\infty)$?
Solution: This was shown to be false by using the counterexample $f_n(x) = 1/x + 1/n, f(x) = 1/x$

My question is how does one construct a sequence of functions for these types of proofs where a counterexample is needed. Whenever I look at solutions, the counterexamples always make sense once seeing them but I'm not sure how to go about constructing one myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach would be the following one:

- Before looking at maps, look at numbers. *A map is an infinite number of numbers*.
- So what is happening for basic sequences? Is it the case that if $x_n \to l$, then $1/x_n \to 1/l$?
- That works (for $n$ large enough) when $l \neq 0$.
- But we start to have an issue when the limit $l$ is equal to zero.
- Hence we need to look for maps that are going to zero *somewhere*. Which is exactly the case of $f(x)=1/x$ *around* $\infty$.
- Then $f_n(x) = 1/x + 1/n$ is *a natural* map converging uniformly to $f$.

Finally, you have to verify that $1/f_n$ doesn't converge uniformly to $1/f$, which is clear if you consider $f_n(n)$.

Comment: Thank you so much, this has really helped clarify the thought process for me!